# rails - change controller variable from view input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have a [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) checkout form where I need to define the amount. The issue is I want the user to enter the amount and save the amount entered but I can't seem to figure how to do that when I need to define an amount before hand...

In my controller#update, I initialized: '@amount = 0'

Is there a way that when the checkout form which heads to controller#update, can take an input from the user that will change @amount?

For example the user wants to have the amount be 500 instead, and enters into an input box this amount which when submitting the form, it registers it into @amount.

```
<%= form_tag artwork_path(@artwork.id), 
    method: :put do %> 
 <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
 class="stripe-button"
 data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
 data-description="Donate"></script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `form_tag`, create a tag for `:amount`, something like:

```
<%= text_field_tag :amount %>
```

and an `:amount` parameter will be submitted if you use a `<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>`. Assign it to the `@amount = params[:amount]` in the controller for further use.

Comment: does :amount have to be created in the database/migration?

Comment: No you don't. It simply allows :amount sent into the controller. It does not save into your db.

Comment: I had to create a [custom stripe form](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) and putting '@amount = params[:amount]' instead of '@amount = artwork_params[:artwork][:amount]' worked for me otherwise I would get an error, something to do with :artwork. My def artwork_params is the same as the one you provided but it has more variables in the permit.

Comment: If you update your answer I will mark it as the answer, otherwise was there a different solution then the change I had to do?